# Etiquette for undoing edit to my answer?

Tags: discussion, editing, etiquette

Someone recently edited an answer I wrote earlier today:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/969737/155629

Usually I'm happy to receive edits, but in this case the edit does not reflect the intention of the post, and the tone ("much much much weaker"), punctuation (!!), and formatting (one sentence all bold, another all italics) are distracting and anyway aren't consistent with the rest of the post, all of which make the answer less professional.

Is there any etiquette that applies to undoing manually these sorts of unwanted changes?

Comment: I'll upgrade my comment to an answer.

Comment: I wonder seeing [such grossly clueless edit to pass through](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/281104), especially being accustomed to [rejection of my unambiguous improvements without valid explanations](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/314282). Were review attitudes mutated to such extent in 2 years?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If it's your post, you should make it reflect what you are trying to say, including tone and whatnot.

When people edit my posts in manners that I feel changes them, I rollback and leave a comment, often using the feature that you can ping someone who edited a post (although their user name will not appear in a tab completion) that these edits should be discussed with me in the comments. My philosophy regarding things which are not typos corrections is "*Point it out, and I will fix it myself if I think that's necessary*".

Comment: I agree with the "point it out and I will fix it myself if I think that's necessary" philosophy to editing answers.  The only time I will edit someone else's answer is to correct a blatant typo (e.g. If they write $x^2 + 2\cdot 2 = x2 + 4$, or something similar).  Questions, on the other hand, I will edit much more freely.

Comment: I agree in principle, but I also tend to fix grammatical and flow issues as well, especially if they significantly increase the readability of the question/answer.